# Answering Amen , Kaddish and Barchu during different parts of davening

Tags: kaddish, shema, tachanun, amen, bircas-krias-shema

Would anyone know where I could find a chart which lists the things your able to answer to (ex. *Amen,Kaddish,Barchu*) during the different parts of *Davening* (*Pesukei DiZimrah,Birchos Krias Shemah,Krias Shema* and *Tachanun*)

Answer (score 2):

In the respective inside back covers of the popular *sidurim* תפלת כל פה (where the chart is in Hebrew) and תהלת ה׳ (where it's in English and according to Chabad-Lubavitch practice).

ArtScroll *sidurim* have the same info on the pages of "*Baruch sheamar*" and "*Yishtabach*", but not in chart form.

Comment: anywhere else ?

Comment: Dunno. Await other answers.